# Insert a link inside the_excerpt(); tag

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to remove the line break between the paragraph and the "Read more". It should continue right after the three dots. Within the paragraph. Hope you understand what I mean.

Is it possible to place the link inside the excerpt? Can you fix it with css?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 

<h2 class="news"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


<?php the_excerpt(); ?>  //this returns the paragraph with three dots

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>  //this should somehow be inside the excerpt


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but the fix is simple.

Add this line after your `foreach()`:

```
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

Now it should stop printing `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css, change the margin of the p tag as 0px.

```
p {
   margin: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: This will work, but it has implications for the entire layout of the site. I suggest a more specific rule.

Comment: true that. @Ben's answer is better.

Comment: have you edited it on the live site? try clearing your cache and load style.css in your browser, refresh it a couple of times till you see the changes in it, then visit the site.

Comment: yeah, that solution removes the <p> tags altogether, making it all go in one line. This (or Ben's) solution, puts Read More on the next line, removing the space in between.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add this line:

```
#news p {margin-bottom:0px;}
```

This will remove the space between the text and the Read More link.

Comment: Ah... your edited question is more clear. These solutions will remove the space after the short text, but it will not add it as part of the line. For that, Blender's answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt), you could do this

> Place this in a theme's functions.php to make the "read more" link to
>   the post

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read the Rest...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: I used this, but if the post is shorter then the value you have decided there wont be a link at all.